# How to calculate estimated current taken by DS3231 when it is wired for alarm

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, embedded

I am developing a system which is considered to be work for long under battery supply. I have a RTC DS3231 configured in alarm mode and it is also used to wakeup the micro controller. The circuit connection is given below which is taken from the datasheet.

[image: RTC circuit]

I am going to use this circuit in project. But the problem  is that i wanna know more about the current consumption of this circuit. In datasheet, active power supply current is given by 200uA ( for vcc 3.63V). 
I am using a 3.3V vcc. Can anyone help me to find the total current consumption by the above circuit( considering I2c pullup resistors and INT,32Khz pullup resistors).

Comment: so why don't you measure it?

Comment: I wanna know the current consumption so as to calculate my battery life

Comment: so why not measure the current? or measure the battery life directly?

Comment: Please understand, i can buy these only after considering the current consumption. If the current consumption is ok for my project, then i will buy it.   How to calculate battery life unless we are unaware of the current consumption?

Comment: what is your budget for V, I?

Comment: did you at least read this ? https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/505

Comment: I am not using a coincell battery instead

Comment: @user3528438, because making one and measuring it is a rubbish way to design circuitry - that's what specifications are for.  The spec' for an IC covers every single one of those millions of ICs made. Measuring one gives you just the one chip you bought. And how do your propose the OP accurately measures to uA precision - with the nearest DMM lying about?

Answer (score 1):

To get the lowest current and have the RTC wakeup your micro you want to turn off VCC to the RTC and run on the battery supply.

[image]

I am assuming that your microprocessor goes to sleep but is still connected to the battery ....so you don't need another battery for the DS3231 RTC battery terminal ...just connect your VCC to it. But you will need a digital port on the Micro to drive the I2C pullups and the DS3231 VCC.
Before your micro goes to sleep the last thing you do is turn off the VCC to I2C pullups and DS3231 VCC. 
The connection on the DS3231 VBat keeps the timing and alarm comparators/INT* going, and that transition brings your micro out of sleep ...you then enable the DS3231 VCC/Pullups and can use I2C to reset your alarm.

I've no idea what micro you are using but something like an ATMEGA328P will cost you about 7-10 uA in deep sleep (at 3-4.2 V LIon with no regulator) and the DS3231 will cost about 2-3 uA running from the VBat terminal. All up if you arrange your I/O correctly you should be easily able to get down to around <15-20 uA total at 3.3 V.

From comments:
When you turn off VCC  to the DS3231, most of the logic inside is then unpowered. The VBat input only keeps the timing, temperature compensation and comparator logic working. There is no 'calculation' for current when running from VCC, simply the bands of current specified in the datasheet.
For example, the VCC current will be as high as 575-650 uA when temperature conversions occur (which will happen automatically every 64 seconds).
You can read Application note [3644](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN3644.pdf) for more details on the temperature conversions. If you are willing to lose timing accuracy you can turn temperature updates off, this reduces the VBat current to the lowest value ....about 2 uA.

To understand what currents will flow you need to compare current flows for VCC and for VBat (two different sections of the datasheet). You don't want the I2C logic powered unless you need to talk to the chip, at all other times you want it to be off.
You can very simply work out the Clk/Data line high and low currents from the pullup values and the leakage currents. You know the I2C Clk speed you will communicate at, and you know the duty cycle of the clock so only you can make these calculations.

In reality, I would not be concerned too much by the absolute values of I2C, temperature or VCC powered functionality ...you are interested in the average current over time. Your microprocessor may range from just 10 uA or so in deep sleep to 20 mA or more (depending on what peripherals you have powered up). Your aim here is of course to keep the processor asleep most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... its helpful. I have doubt why Active Battery current is 70uA and but Timekeeping is 2uA. Also when vcc is connected to RTC, may i wanna communicate with RTC through I2C. How to calculate that current taken for communication

Comment: I am not bothering about the coincell battery and instead bothering about the main battery lifetime. Your answer is helpful for me and thank you. Will you please tell me how to do the current calculation while RTC is connected on Vcc

Comment: Added to answer....

Comment: @Jack Creasey I wanted to ask about the DS3231M, is there a way to deactivate the temperature connections? What is the average current drawn of this RTC?

Comment: @NickG Yes you can disable temperature checks. Read the application note, the details are in there.

Comment: @JackCreasey Thanks for the answer, I have seen the application note. However, since I have the 'M' version of the RTC, I cannot find the required registers to disable the temperature. As a result, when powering from the battery, it gives a 2uA IBatt, which is great, but also there is an unacceptably high IBattC of 575uA.

Comment: @NickG Clearly the DS3232M is different silicon or at least fused differently.

Comment: @JackCreasey Could you help me clear out the current consumption of this IC? Can it get down to <10uA current consumption, or is it not worth it?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how to manage power on this device.

Comment: @user ....how so? Please explain what you think is wrong.

Comment: @JackCreasey see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If your device is battery powered you don't need VCC at all. Check the datasheet, page 10, "Power Control" and "VBAT operation".

If you power the DS3231 from just VBAT it will start up in a low power state with the oscillator disabled. When the microcontroller first talks to it over I2C by sending its address the oscillator will start up. The MCU should configure the DS3231 as required, setting the time and enabling any outputs or alarms it needs.

The I2C bus can be pulled up to VBAT. Once I2C activity finishes the DS3231 will go into low power mode, detailed on page 3:

[image]

As you can see you can expect around 3uA in this mode, with an increase to 575uA every 64 seconds as the DS3231 does its temperature compensation cycle.

You only need VCC if you intend to have the rest of the system powered off. For example if you powered the MCU down the I2C pull-ups would begin to reverse-power it if they were tied to VBAT, so the option to use VCC is available. If you run the MCU from VBAT as well there is no issue.

Comment: Not sure why this was modded down, it's correct. Care to explain?